# CSS selector to match elements by attribute's name start

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

Is there any CSS selector to match these elements? (I need it for `adblocker` config, looked at `W3C selectors` document - no hints found there. **Generic** solution needed because **part after `data-d-` gets randomized by the site**).

```
<div data-d-9y3x>
<div data-d-m01>
<div data-d-whatever>
```

Comment: As far as I know, the *starts with* match is possible only for attribute values and not the for the attribute name. You would more than likely have to use three selectors in CSS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to select elements based on the presence of an attribute whose name is *`starting with`* a certain value. The *`starts with`* selection is only possible for attribute values.

Such a selector is not mentioned in the [CSS Selectors Level 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-selectors) also and so it doesn't look like it would be available anytime soon.

You have the following choices:

- Use group of selectors with all possible attribute name values in the format `element[attribute-name]`. But this option is not viable when the exact attribute names are not fixed/unknown.
- Use JavaScript (or some other scripting library of your preference). Below is a very quick rough sample for the benefit of future visitors.

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  var attr = el[i].attributes; /* get all attributes on the element */
  for (var j = 0; j < attr.length; j++) {
    if (attr[j].name.indexOf('data-') == 0) { /* if element has an attribute whose name has data- */
      el[i].style.color = 'red';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div data-d-9y3x>Some</div>
<div data-d-m01>text</div>
<div data-d-whatever>content</div>
<div test-data-d-whatever>and</div>
<div d-whatever>more</div>
<div testdata-d-whatever>...</div>
```

Comment: i had a hope CSS is flexible enough :). I'm already done with some JS + Greasemonkey help.

Comment: @Max: I have added a JS sample just in-case.

Comment: cheers. yep, done the same in greasemonkey, let it be for future readers of your answer. off-topic: i tweak adblock for 5th time on that site :) they seem to adapt their page with more and more cunning tricks, just marvel at this "invisible fight" for user clicks on ads :). Cheers, i didn't know you can add working code snippets in SO.

Answer (score 1):

With `ES6+` you can use spread operator (`...`) and then filter those element that their attribute names' start with `data-d-`:

```js
var res = [...document.querySelectorAll("*")]
    .filter(t => [...t.attributes]
                 .filter(({ name }) => name.startsWith("data-d-")).length > 0)

console.log(res);
```

```html
<div data-d-9y3x>Some</div>
<div data-d-m01>text</div>
<div data-d-whatever>content</div>
<div test-data-d-whatever>and</div>
<div d-whatever>more</div>
<div testdata-d-whatever>...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> @Alireza_Ahmadi answer is very great and could be extended to use a primary node selector to target preciselly a qualified attribute...

Standard selector with jQ for a dedicated attr would be : `jQuery('[role="field-form"]')`

```
var res = [...(jQuery('[role="field-form"]').get())]
    .filter(t => [...t.attributes]
                 .filter(({ name }) => name.startsWith("formula_")).length > 0)
```