css selector start with or end with but with out an attribute
my html looks similar to this:
this lwc- is common and rest is dynamic. I want to style this heading by using css only 'begins with - a[href^="https"]' some thing like this.


h2[^lwc-] {color: red;}
<h2 lwc-3tgmr21liqd>Some Heading Text</h2>



not sure how to call this one, i tried the above one but not working. Please note this h2 element doesn't have any classes or ids or any attributes.
appreciate your help, and excuse any flaws.

So what is lwc-3tgmr21liqd..? It's not an attribute so there is nothing to select AFAICT. How is it generated? Could you make it a data-attribute? data-ref=lwc-3tgmr21liqd

this lwc-**** is a dynamic one which is coming from backend. i dont have access to that code to modify. also i have some more h2 tags in different sections like this to change the color.

Then I think you will have to rethink your approach. CSS can't select this AFAIK. JS maybe?

I would discuss with the person making the "backend" and try to change this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980250/css-selector-to-match-elements-by-attributes-name-start

While it's not a 'proper' attribute, getAttributeNames() will find it so you could plod through all h2s in JS perhaps converting it to a 'proper' attribute by setting data-lwc-...or something.
